Cognitive Service and Communication service Connection Error
I got the Error

An error has occurred while connecting "ACSTestService". Try again or
select another cognitive service

while I connect cognitive service to my Azure Communication Service how to resolve it
I want to connect the Azure Cognitive Service to My Azure Communication Service And make an Inbound PSTN call IVR

Even I got the same error then made some changes you can check below.

Here, I have assigned the "Cognitive service user" role to my Azure communication service. It enables the access to communicate with my cognitive service (speech-to-text), you can check the same in MS_DOC.

Navigate to Azure communication service<Identity< enable managed Identity< Add role assignments.

Then Go to the Settings<cognitive services and connect with your cognitive service.

Result:


I want to connect the Azure Cognitive Service to My Azure Communication Service And make an Inbound PSTN call IVR


Here, you need to enable the Phone calling option in Telephony and SMS menu. before that you need purchase the phone number to make an outbound call.


